# C Programming Help : Calculates and print the sum and product of the multiples of 3 from 1 to 30

Tags: c

C Programming Help : Calculates and print the sum and product of the multiples of 3 from 1 to 30

Kindly seeking assistance for this programming question!I'm still learning C programming. Any tips and advice are welcome and greatly appreciated!

Kindly help to review the code that I have written.

```
write a C program that calculates and prints the sum and product of the multiples of 3 from 1 to 30, as shown below
Sum is 165
Product is 214277011200*/

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
    int int1, sum, product;
    unsigned int i;

    sum = 0;
    product = 1;
    int1 =1;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) //mistake, after a for loop there should not be a ';' ...
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) 
        {
            sum += i;
            product *= i;
            
        }
    }
    printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
    printf("Product is %d", product);


}
```

Comment: This question suits codereview.stackexchange.com more

Comment: Does your program provide the required answer? If so, then you're done. If not, what is EXACTLY your question?

Comment: Does this work? I think you'll need a larger integer type than int, which is probably 32-bits, to represent 214277011200.

Comment: You can change your for loop so that it only considers the steps of three, rather than trying every number 1-30 and rejecting non-multiples of 3. And have you tried compiling the code with warnings turned on? I can see one thing I expect would be warned about.

Comment: My program does not provide the required answer. It does for sum, but not product.

Comment: Weirdest thing of all, is that the result gives me a negative number? 

The sum is correct at 165.

But the product generated from this code is : -471353600. 

Have tried another datatype, and it still gives  me the same anser!

Comment: Which other data type? `long long` should work, or if you have `#include <stdint.h>` then `int64_t`. You will need to change the %d to match whichever data type you use too.

Comment: What does `int1 = 1`?

Comment: I solved it by changing the format specifier ... I used %d to call a long long datatype.

Thank you kind souls for your comments, never would've done it without you guys.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned from the posts, when I first ran the code, the product was a negative number which lead me to believe that an overflow occured. An int type is typically 32 bits so therefore you must use a 64 bit type which is a long. Then in the printf string %d is for int which will still display the wrong value so you must change that to %ld for long int. Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
    long int1, sum, product;
    unsigned int i;

    sum = 0;
    product = 1;
    int1 =1;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) //mistake, after a for loop there should not be a ';' ...
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) 
        {
            sum += i;
            product *= i;
            
        }
    }
    printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
    printf("Product is %ld", product);


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother! I now know the importance of datatypes, and when to use different datatypes. 

I took them for granted, and was looking into the wrong area!

Comment: Please upvote my response if you like my answer. It will really help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `product` will overflow because it's an `int`. So, use `long long` instead.

You're doing extra/unnecessary loop iterations. There's no need to use `if ((i % 3) == 0)` inside the loop.

The first number in `1-30` that is a multiple of `3` is ... `3`

Simply start at `3` and increment by 3 and eliminate the `if`.

It reduces the number of iterations by 3x and eliminates the divide/remainder [which is somewhat slow].

Also, it eliminates condtional branching within the loop, making it faster.

Also, `int1` is set but *not* used. If you had compiled with `-Wall` [which I recommend *always* doing], this would have been flagged by the compiler.

Here's the refactored code:

```
/* write a C program that calculates and prints the sum and product of the
multiples of 3 from 1 to 30, as shown below
Sum is 165
Product is 214277011200*/

#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
#ifdef BUG
    int int1, sum, product;
#else
    long long sum, product;
#endif
    unsigned int i;

    sum = 0;
    product = 1;
    // int1 is unused
#ifdef BUG
    int1 = 1;
#endif

    // mistake, after a for loop there should not be a ';' ...
#ifdef ORIG
    for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            sum += i;
            product *= i;
        }
    }
#else
    for (i = 3; i <= 30; i += 3) {
        sum += i;
        product *= i;
    }
#endif

#ifdef BUG
    printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
    printf("Product is %d\n", product);
#else
    printf("Sum is %lld\n", sum);
    printf("Product is %lld\n", product);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother, I am learning so much from you guys who know how to optimize code!

I will remember your advice and implement it when I code in the future. Thank you for taking the time to offer tips and advice to a new programmer. Cheers!

Comment: May I ask you kind sir, what is '-Wall'? How do I compile with '-Wall'?

Comment: `-Wall` is a command line option that you give to `gcc` [or `clang`]. It tells the compiler to set most warnings on. You can also add `-Wextra`. (e.g.) `gcc -c -Wall mysource.c` The compiler will then look for suspicious things, such as a variable that is not initialized in all conditional cases or one that is defined, assigned to, but the result is never used [what happened in your case].  See `man gcc` as it will explain it best. If you want to see it work, compile your original code with the option and you'll see it flag a statement or two.